# How to track CPU Utilization of Service in windows by powershell

Tags: powershell, cpu-usage

I usually use resource monitor to track the CPU utilization. But, now I want to track them by powershell. I just know `Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.CPU -gt 100 }` and  `(Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples | Where-Object {$_.CookedValue -gt 5}` to get CPU information of process. How to track the CPU of Service just like Resource monitor

Answer (score -1):

> $CPU=(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_processor | Measure-Object -Property loadpercentage -Average).Average
> $CPU

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).